# Adding Nodes to LinkeList

Tags: java, nodes

I am trying to make this method add a Node in the Linked List. The first part works and I am able to add a node in positions 2 and up. But when I try to add it to position 1(0), it fails.

```
public boolean add(double val, int pos)
{
   Node t = root;
   int count = 1;
   Node n = new Node();
   while(t != null)
   {
      if(pos-1 == count)
      {
           n.next = t.next;
           t.next = n;
      }
      else if(pos == 1)
      {
           n.next = t;
           t = n;
      }
      count++;
      t = t.next; 
    }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: How exactly does it 'fail'?

Comment: It just displays the nodes I made originally.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to handle adding to front of list as an edge case by replacing the root, but you are not assigning the new node to the root, you are assigning it to the local variable t (which goes out of scope).

Try this change:

```
     ...
      else if(pos == 1)
      {
           n.next = t;
           root = n;//NOT t = n;
      }
     ...
```

Comment: This works as far as adding the new node to the start of the list, but all of the other nodes are gone.

Comment: it displays the first and last node only

Comment: You need to provide more code then, and better explain how the add method should work. Why are you doing `if(pos-1 == count)` ? It will add the node when position is 1 less than count, for example, adding at position 2 will happen when count is 1. I'm confused by that